# nested for loop prime checker

Tags: java, for-loop, nested, primes

here is my code Im kinda new to programming any way the goal of the program is to out put all the primes numbers between 0 and a user inputted value, each on their own line

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.*;

public class Sforprime{

  public static void main (String[] args){
    double box = 0;
    double boxxx = 0;
    int po = 0;
    int blub = 0;
    int no = 1;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("input cieling number");
    box = scan.nextInt();
    boxxx = Math.sqrt(box);
    for (int batman = (int)box; batman >= 0; batman--){
      if (no == 1){
        no = 0;
      }
      else if (po == 0){
        System.out.println(blub);
        po = 0;
      }
      blub = batman;

      for (int mot = (int)boxxx; mot >= 2; mot--){
        if (po == 1 ){
        }
        else if (box%mot == 0){
          po++;
        }  
      }
      if (po == 0){
        System.out.println(blub);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What ends up happening is it doesn't do anything after you input the number. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have initialised int mot = (int) boxxx 
box% mot will be 0 and po will always get incremented to 1 and hence never gets printed. Initialise mot=boxxx-1. But suggest you to use the above program as it is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic:

```
        int n,p;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(“Enter required number upto which prime numbers are needed: ”);
        n=s.nextInt();
        for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
        {
            p=0;
            for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
            {
                if(i%j==0)
                p=1;
            }
            if(p==0)
                System.out.println(i);
        }
```

Comment: They wanted to know - "What am i doing wrong here?" Does this answer that?